# How to make cmake script for ecpg and qt project?

Tags: qt, cmake, code-generation, ecpg

How to make cmake build script for project that use ecpg code generation and qt moc compiler?

Also how to add code generation in cmake (which is easy in make)?

Comment: Have you solved this? Otherwise I can post how we added the use of ecpg to generate a c-file in cmake.

Comment: @user1766169 No I didn't solved it (and also I don't have to anymore). But if you have an answer please post it, so every body could know it.

Comment: I added an answer for code generation in cmake.

Comment: @user1766169 Where can I see it??

Comment: Sorry. For some reason I had deleted my answer. I added it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we added code generation for ecpg in cmake.

```
set( PGSQL_CMD "/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/ecpg" )
set( PGSQL_ARG "input_file.pgc" )
add_custom_command( OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output_file.c
                    COMMAND ${PGSQL_CMD} ${PGSQL_ARG}
                    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input_file.pgc
                    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

Comment: How this solution should look for multiple pgc files. Does I need to write add_custom_command every time?
Also I think ecpg program could be mentioned without absolute path, because after postgreSQL upgrade it would became broken.

Comment: Yes, you would need to write one add_custom_command for each pgc-file.